# Google Places Library OVER_QUERY_LIMIT with new API key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using the Places libary in my javascript application. It works fine when I use the `service.nearbySearch()` method to look up nearby places. When I then go to make a `service.getDetails()` request I get an `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` status for each request. In my Developer Console, I can track every request made to the Google Maps JavaScript API v3, but I dont get any results from the places API.

Heres some of the code:

```
// How I load the library 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=API_KEY"></script>

// My places request
var places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var request = {
    location: location,
    radius: radius,
    types: [type]
  };

places.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status, pagination) {

    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

      // Get the details for each place
      var detailsRequest = { placeId: results[i].id }

      places.getDetails(detailsRequest, function(place, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            console.log('PLACE', place)
        } else {
            console.log('STATUS', status)
        }        
    })              
  };
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should look up what `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` means in the Google Maps documentation.

Comment: I know what it means. I'm not hitting anywhere near the 1k limit. Much less am I able to track how many requests I'm making associated with my API key. The problem is that it shouldnt be returning that at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer was that I was requesting the `.getDetails()` method too fast. [Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits).

I was iterating over dozens of locations and requesting too many too fast. Often times I would only get the first 10 or 12 our of 60+ results before the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error.

I moved the call to `.getDetails()` to the click event for the marker. That way only one request is sent at a time.

Comment: I have the same problem, but we store PlaceID on the database (because we want the retailer to update its information), and when we load all the retailers on map, we got blocked by the API. I am not finding a way to avoid this problem, since the only API that returns the location (at least) is the getDetails API. Any other idea on how to do that without storing all the details on database? =/

Comment: @WagnerBertoliniJunior did you find a solution? For me, I need to get the nearbySearch places' website URLs which are only in the getDetails response :(

Comment: @benmccallum no. It seems da they don't want us to do that. I made my own retry logic and keep asking data when they allow me to do that. This reduces the flow of reading data. Another thing that I have learnt is that if you open a new windows/browser things seem to start from the beginning, just a felling, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

Also ran into the same issue. Seems like you have a pool of 9 or 10 requests you can exhaust, and then get allowance for an additional request every 1s.

Some people have said that the server-side version of the API allows for 50 requests per second, so I'm guessing Google is trying to prevent client-side instances overloading them, which makes sense.

For me, it was enough to just have the UI show spinners while the getDetails result/s come in. So I just throttled the requests after the first 9 or 10 like so:

```
nearbySearchCallback: function (places, status) {
  var that = this;
  if (status === window.google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
      // You seem to have a pool of 9 or 10 requests to exhaust,
      // then you get another request every second therein. 
      (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          service.getDetails({ placeId: places[i].place_id }, that.getDetailsCallback);
        }, i < 9 ? 0 : 1000 * i);
      })(i);
    }
  }
},
getDetailsCallback: function (place, status) {  /* ... */ }
```